# fibonacci using mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, fibonacci, do-loops

New to Mathematica, I am trying to print the out the first 50 Fibonacci numbers using a Do loop, but can't seem to make it work. I know there is a built-in function that returns the Fibonacci sequence given a number but I want to implement it using a Do loop. Any help would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: you actually want `Table` or `Nest`, but really you need to show the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31593/18476

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
a = 0; b = 1; terms = {a, b};

Do[
  {a, b} = {b, a + b};
  terms = {terms, b},
  {50 - 2}
];

Flatten@terms
```

I'm sure there are fancier ways.

Answer (score 1):

From [An Introduction to Programming with Mathematica](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Programming-Mathematica-Paul-Wellin/dp/0521846781/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1486460361&sr=8-1&keywords=introduction+to+programming+with+mathematica), page 178.

Chapter 7. Recursion

```
F[1] = 1;
F[2] = 1;
F[n_] := F[n - 2] + F[n - 1] /; n > 2
```

"As it turns out, the condition `/; n > 2` is unnecessary because Mathematica looks up specific rules such as `F[1] = 1` before more general rules like that for `F[n]`.  Here is a table of the first ten Fibonacci numbers."

```
Table[F[i], {i, 1, 10}]
```

> {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55}

However, for adequate speed also use [memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html):

```
F[1] = 1;
F[2] = 1;
F[n_] := F[n] = F[n - 2] + F[n - 1]

Table[F[i], {i, 1, 50}]
```

> {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 
>   2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 
>   317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 
>   14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 
>   267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073, 
>   4807526976, 7778742049, 12586269025}

Answer (score 0):

using `Nest`

```
Nest[ Append[#, Total@#[[-2 ;;]]] &  , {1, 1}, 10]
```

> {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144}

using `Table`

```
Module[{last = 1, lastp = 1, next}, Join[{lastp, last},
  Table[next = last + lastp ; lastp = last ; last = next , {10}] ]]
```

> {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144}

`Do` with `Reap/Sow`:

```
Reap[Module[{last = 1, lastp = 1 }, Sow[lastp]; Sow[last];
   Do[  {lastp, last} = {last, Sow[last + lastp]} ; , {10}] ]][[2, 1]]
```

> {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144}